# How do i change the loop so it chooses specific elements in a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

As the title says, how do i change the loop so it chooses specific elements in a list?

In this case i need to choose and only use the first 10 elements.

```
AGE_DATA =[22, 38, 26, 35, 35, 54, 2, 67, 14, 4, 68, 30, 41, 14, 95, 2]

def comAvAge(arg1: list):
   count = 0
   sum = 0
   for x in arg1:
      sum = sum + x
      count = count + 1
   avg = sum / count
   return avg

titanicAge = comAvAge(AGE_DATA) 
print(titanicAge)
```

Comment: Choosing first 10 elements is just list slicing. arg1[0:10]

Comment: You could just do `for x in range(10): sum = sum + arg1[x]....`

Comment: Or even `sumx = sum(arg1[:10])` / `count = 10` / `avg = sumx / count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for x in arg1[0:10]:
    sum = sum + x
    count = count + 1
avg = sum / count
```